# MEAN stack authentication

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am new to the MEAN stack and am struggling to find any appropriate literature, or helpful tutorials for my problem.

I am developing a  blog site, which will also have an admin content management system for adding new blog articles. I want to be able to login to the system and access restricted content. The content on specific URL's can only be viewed if the user is logged in and so on...

I am struggling to find a good authentication tutorial that goes through the process step by step. As I am new too the syntax and semantics of AngularJS and NodeJS, I need something that will break down each process and define the methods.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for my problem?

Comment: have you tried this?  http://passportjs.org/guide/

Comment: That's really what I'm looking for.. I want a reasonably comprehensive walk through of how authentication and authorization can be handled @ArnaldoCapo

Comment: `I want a reasonably comprehensive walk through` ...  this isn't the right place for that ...let google be your friend

Comment: @charlietfl I know... I was simply asking if anyone would be able to point me in the right direction...

Comment: I don't think there's a one place here it is ALL that you need to know about authentication.  You should start with understanding how middleware works. On how HTTP requests/responses are handles throughout NodeJS. Also, how Node.JS is an event base paradigm, routes, MVC, etc..

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I have recently started myself.
Take a look at meanjs.org or even masteringmean.com
Perhaps this video could help you?

https://masteringmean.com/lessons/601-Angular-e2e-Protractor-Testing-Interacting-with-Thirdparty-Sites

I remember having timing issues at one point, which is actually mentioned here.
I do agree as well that perhaps its useful to look at understanding middleware and how to respond to requests with the connect framework.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple MEAN stack implementation (but using a DEPLOYD nodejs framework) This you can use for rapid learning of MEAN stack. (Disclosure: I'm a contributor to this MarsCMS)
https://github.com/moorthi07/MarsCMS/

Answer (score -1):

@user37... Checkout satellizer, https://github.com/sahat/satellizer.
It's a complete token based Oauth with a bonus for social logins.
Reply back here if you have any Qs.